# Adding/updating navigation properties in EF CF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I know that this has been asked multiple times here on SO, but I cannot find a definitive answer on how to add or update navigation properties in EF CF.

Entities (simplified):

```
 public class Basket : EntityBase
    {
        public virtual List<Fruit> TaggedFruits { get; set; }
    } 

    public class Fruit : EntityBase
        {

        }
```

ActionResult:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveTags(Basket basket, int[] selectedFruits)
        {
        basket.TaggedFruits = new List<Fruits>();

        foreach (int guid in selectedFruits)
            basket.TaggedFruits.Add(repository.Fruits.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == guid));

        using (var context = new EFDbContext())
        {
            context.Baskets.Attach(basket);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("GetBasket", new {guid = basket.Guid});
    }
```

I've tried multiple iterations of the SaveTags method above, but never got it to work.  This one throws:

**An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**

After researching here and other sites, the error obviously states that mixing my repository pattern and the DBContext in the method is causing a conflict.

If I move the tagging to the repository, with the following methods:

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult SaveTags(Basket basket, int[] selectedFruits)
            {
                   List<Fruit> taggedFruits = new List<Fruit>();
           foreach (int guid in selectedFruits)
               taggedFruits.Add(new Fruit {Id = guid});

           libraryRepository.TagBasket(basket, taggedFruits);

            return RedirectToAction("GetBasket", new {guid = basket.Guid});
        }



/*in repository*/
    public void TagBasket(Basket basket, List<Fruit> fruits )
            {
                basket.Taggedfruits = new List<Fruit>();
                foreach (var fruit in fruits)
                {
                    basket.Taggedfruits.Add(Fruit);
                }


            context.Baskets.Attach(basket);
       context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Then no changes are committed to the database.  Nothing happens, at all.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I've been fighting this for way to long, thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you are only attaching the entity (= setting state to `Unchanged`) and then call `SaveChanges`. You are telling EF in that case that nothing has changed -> nothing happens.

To change the relationships between `Basket` and `TaggedFruits` you must load the original fruits collection of the basket from the database and then either remove or add the tagged fruits from/to the loaded fruit collection of the basket according to the Ids in your Id collection:

```
public void TagBasket(Basket basket, List<Fruit> fruits)
{
    var basketInDB = context.Baskets.Include(b => b.Taggedfruits)
        .Single(b => b.Id == basket.Id);

    foreach (var fruitInDB in basketInDB.Taggedfruits.ToList())
        if (!fruits.Any(f => f.Id == fruitInDB.Id))
            basketInDB.Taggedfruits.Remove(fruitInDB);

    foreach (var fruit in fruits)
        if (!basketInDB.Taggedfruits.Any(f => f.Id == fruit.Id))
        {
            var newFruit = new Fruit { Id = fruit.Id };
            context.Fruits.Attach(newFruit);
            basketInDB.TaggedFruits.Add(newFruit);
        }

    // Next line is only necessary if other properties in basket
    // could have been changed in your view
    context.Entry(basketInDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(basket);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can also just pass in the `int[] selectedFruits` collection into this method because only the ids are needed.

Comment: I could kiss you.  Thanks.  Only line I changed was:
context.Entry(basketInDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(basket);
I set it to
context.Entry(basketInDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(basketInDB);
because I was losing data that wasn't in the basket object passed to the method.  Is there any problem with this?  It seems to persist all of the older data that I inteded to keep, but still update the relationship.  That cool?

Comment: @JeffBorden: No, there is no problem with this, but it makes the line redundant (you are updating an entity with itself = No update at all). Just remove the line completely, it is only for other scalar properties on basket and does not affect updating the relationships to TaggedFruits.